# all Heroku command line started failing

Tags: heroku

It used to work just fine. Not sure what has changed,
i get this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- netrc (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ilan kasan/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/auth.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ilan kasan/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/bin/heroku:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by updating the heroku gem

gem update heroku

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to occur after the latest Windows7 update. I found a proposed solution in the issue list of Heroku: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/298

> I fixed it again by deleting `/users/me/.heroku/client` and reinstalling
>   from https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

So delete `~/.heroku/client` folder and reinstal Heroku Toolbelt. I hope it helps.